# 'MyModel' object is not iterable

Tags: django

I getting `'YesNo' object is not iterable`.
`..apps/wadofstuff/django/serializers/base.py in serialize, line 44`

```
def yes_add(request, id):
    if request.is_ajax:
        form = YesNoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            user = request.user
            value = 'yes'
            item = Item.objects.get(id=id)
            yes = YesNo(value=value, user=user, item=item, content=content)
            yes.save()
            response = HttpResponse()
            response['Content-Type'] = "text/javascript"
            response.write(serializers.serialize("json", yes))
            return response
```

But i used something like this, but with query set containing several instances of one of my model. Has someone has any tips?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could just wrap your instance in a list:

```
response.write(serializers.serialize("json", [yes])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
item = Item.objects.filter(id=id)
```

This will return serializable object.